# Proyectos por capas en GIT (github) aplicando control de versiones, con alimientacion de actualizaciones

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-commit, git-pull

Proyectos por capas en GIT (github/gitlab) aplicando control de versiones

Tengo aceso a los siguientes tres proyectos:

1. Tipo LAMP Stack Docker.
2. Personalizacion del Projecto 1, adecuaciones en variables de entorno, etc.
3. Projecto Web.

mi estructura local es la siguiente:

```
Home
|
+---- LH-2          # Proyecto para la creacion de un Stack LAMP + otras utilidades en Docker
|
|
+---- LH-2 (Custom) # Clonado del proyecto Original Docker + Cambios internos Custom
      |
      +---- Web App # Projecto Web App que se ejecuta sobre LH-2 (Custom)
```

Teniendo en cuenta que p# es el numero de proyecto 1,2 y 3

***Diagrama del escenario conceptual:***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Vista conceptual estructura de archivos:***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1. En LH-2 (p1) Normalmente hago cambios locales, hago los commit y luego lo push al remoto (github) Siempre esta actualizado en los dos lugares
2. [Consulta] En LH-2 (Custom, p2) este tiene su propio repositorio, por lo tanto cuando hago commit push es enviado a otro repositorio diferente al p1, me queda la duda de como puedo hacer para seguir recibiendo actualizaciones de p1 sin que se sobre-escriban mis cambios locales personalizados. y como le hago para cuando hago commit/push enviar mis actualizaciones al respositorio de p2 en lugar de p1.

El problema es que no me basta con los comando:

```
git pull
git commit
git push
```

El diagrama de comunicacion entre repositorio esperado seria el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Pregunta:*** Cual seria la secuencia correcta de comandos a ejecutar para mantener el control de versiones del p2 sincronizado con las actualizaciones de p1, pero que al momento de hacer commit/push esto vaya al repositorio de p1.

Answer (score 1):

Digamos que tienes dos remotos. `upstream` es el origen, donde está por así decirlo "la fuente de verdad". `origin` es el destino, adonde tú quieres pushear tus cambios. Habrías hecho algo como

```
git init
git remote add upstream git@github.com:empresa/proyecto-lamp.git
git remote add origin git@github.com:arcanis/clon-de-lamp.git
```

Si tú creas una rama local para hacer seguimiento de la rama master de upstream:

```
  git checkout -b rama_local upstream/master
```

Esa rama quedará asociada a `upstream` y los siguientes `pull` se traerán desde allá. En tu archivo `.git/config` habrá una entrada asociando, además, las ramas

```
 [branch "rama_local"]
     remote = upstream
     merge = refs/heads/master
```

Hasta este minuto, si tú haces `git push` lo más probable será que se intente enviar esos commits a `upstream/master` o a `upstream/rama_local`  (dependiendo de tu configuración global). Tú puedes cambiar ese comportamiento fijando el valor de  `push.default` para asumir por defecto que el target del push es una rama con el mismo nombre:

```
   git config push.default current
```

y el valor de `remote.pushDefault`  para usar `origin` por defecto:

```
   git config remote.pushdefault origin
```

De esta manera, aunque el comportamiento de `git pull` no ha cambiado (sigue obedeciendo lo que dice el archivo `.git/config`) el comportamiento de `git push` sí cambió. Ahora, ante la ausencia de otros parámetros, `git push` asume que el objetivo es una rama con el mismo nombre en el remoto `origin`. En este caso `origin/rama_local`

Este flujo que describes se conoce como triangular workflow, por si quieres buscar más info al respecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: muchas gracias ... si es algo mas o menos asi solo que cambia un poco o es mas complejo, agregare una imagen mas de diagrama basado en que esta en github y que esta en local.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/egq5L.jpg

Comment: Ya, pero en este caso el LH2-clon viene siendo el pivote del triángulo. Otros locales y otras webapps que siguen el flujo tradicional no participan del flujo triangular, pero da igual porque no es excluyente

Comment: es correcto, el p3 (WebApp) simplemente va dentro de la carpeta project y esa la ignoro ... el pivote que seria el clon es donde queda el asunto ... no me queda claro si puedo actualizarlo como fork directamente entre github original y github clon, o si debo aplicarlo como esta en el diagrama, bajar del github original al clon local... para despues subirlo al github clon

Comment: no es un triangulo por que del clon nunca envia nada al original...

Comment: buen punto. Pero por lo mismo es un poco más simple. El flujo siempre es aguas abajo. El upstream es tu única fuente de verdad, y tú eres la única fuente de verdad para el eslabón siguiente.

Comment: Si gracias a tu respuesta estoy haciendo pruebas con el tema de los comando a ver como organizo la configuracion local de los proyectos... te pido permiso para editar y agregar en tu respuesta lo que al final termine realizando y quede todo junto, vale?

Comment: Pero... no necesitas ponerlo en la respuesta, pedes añadirlo a tu misma pregunta cuidando de separar el contenido original usando una linea (varios guiones seguidos) y empezar la segunda parte con **Edit**  en negrita.

Comment: ok dejame ver como lo hago saludos, de casualidad sabes de docker???

Comment: sólo lo suficiente para echar a andar imágenes, pero nada más